# Keras definition of input shape - can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple

Tags: python, keras, input, shapes

following this tutorial [CartPole Neural Network](https://pylessons.com/CartPole-PER-CNN/), I am trying to create my own version of this. In the tutorial code itself, there is an python error in the `replay` function, when defining the state numpay array like this, where `batch_size` is 32 and the `state_size` is 4 (frames) * 160 (pixel height) + 240 (pixel width):

```
 state = np.zeros((self.batch_size,) + self.state_size)
```

throws the error

```
can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple
```

The `state` variable is then populated, as per the tutorial:

`for i in range(len(minibatch)):
state[i] = minibatch[i][0]`

Here is my confusion:
what is the correct shape of this `state` variable, since the initial declaration `np.zeros` line of the tutorial is incorrect? I tried providing a numpy array of shape `(32,4,160,240)`, being 32 arrays of individual inputs. resulting in this error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 153600 but received input with shape [32, 4, 160, 240]
```

Then I thought, I need to reshape it to a one-dimensional array, having an empty zero-th dimension, using these 2 lines:

`state = np.reshape(state, (4 * 160 * 240 ))
state = np.expand_dims(state, axis=0)`

However, that yields me the error

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 4915200 into shape (153600,)
```

TLDR: what is the purpose of this np.zeros((shape) + int) call, why does it fail for me, and what is the expected shape of the input numpy array, having 32 batch samples of a total of 153600 input nodes?

Thank you.

Comment: update: according to the predict method API, the input can be "or a list of arrays (in case the model has multiple inputs)." so I created an empty list and appended the batches to it, which results in this error:

ValueError: Layer sequential expects 1 inputs, but it received 32 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None, 4, 160, 240) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:1' shape=(None, 4, 160, 240) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:2' ..

how to define multiple numpy arrays as input that is valid for the predict method?

Answer (score 0):

The `np.zeros` creates a NumPy array of zeroes on the size that you define.

You are trying to concatenate batch_size with state_size, but you do that:

```
(self.batch_size,) + self.state_size
```

Try to remove the parenthesis and comma:

```
 state = np.zeros(self.batch_size + self.state_size)
```

Comment: that would create a single array with 32 + 153600 entries, which is not matching the input count of the network. what I guess I need is an array of 32 entries of the individual batches, which have 153600 entries each.